# Pupil and Iris diameter detection and measurement ios

Tags: ios, biometrics

Ive been looking through the web to find a way to measure the diameter of pupils and iris. I know you can use CIDetector and CIFaceFeature classes to detect a persons face, eye and mouth locations, but there isn't anything for specific eye information (i.e pupil and iris diameter). I have seen a few apps already on the market but all the reviews say that they are not accurate and a waste of money. If anyone has done this or has a clue as to where to start (aside form CIDetector and CIFaceFeature) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe with openCV. You have to code the functions yourself

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the eye positions and grab a box of pixels around it you can then go through with a simple loop grabbing the black pixels and white pixels giving you the relevant sections, from there you can measure the size in pixels however to convert this to a real life size you would have to have a scale somewhere on the picture for the computer to convert. This would all require coding but I imagine getting the position on the eyes is the hard bit. For an added bit of accuracy run it in both eyes and average the values.

Comment: Well CIDetector and CIFaceFeature already gives you a good aproximation of where the eyes are located, what i need to figure out is to distinct the pupil and iris and then find measurements, but your idea is great! Thanks for the thought!

Comment: In a little more detail, to differentiate between the pieces you can use the fact that eyes are comprised of 3 pieces each different colours, the black part, the white part and the coloured part (in crude terms). The coloured part is the only part that varies so we will just leave that as the remainder, and the other 2 pieces can be done simply checking if each of the RGB values is above say 220 for white and less than say 30 for black. Change those values till you get a good approximation.(cont)

Comment: (cont) Copying each of the pixels to an array depending on the category and using that you can  apply some algorithms to clear up spear pixels and if you are feeling fancy write an algorithm to check the shapes are roughly what you expect, E.G. the black part should be roughly circular. Hope that is enough information <sidenote> I am only now realizing that I should have probably just edited the answer but now I shall just leave it as comments. </sidenote>

Answer (score 1):

After get eye positions, you can use some filters to try eliminate iris and sclera (white part of eye). So you can use another filter to raise contrast between iris and pupil. After that you can count pixel of iris and have a pixel measurement. As Andy A. told you will need a scale to convert to real measures.

Therefore this will be easier if you have a NIR camera to acquire images. With infrared the eye parts (pupil, iris and sclera) will have a better contrast.

We use NIR to acquire iris, create a template from it and match to authenticate a person. If you want we can help you if that filters I told before. As jcesar told, OpenCV has many filters to do this work.

Comment: What do you mean "eliminate iris and sclera"? And I am using openCV to do the image filtering, but i dont know which filters would work best for this problem, or in what order to use them. Sadly im still new to image processing.

Comment: If you are new in image processing and have not much theorical knowledge, you can use Gimp to test several filters and try with method of "tentative and error". I will try to find some time to do some experiences and tell you the order of filter.